# Enforcing Schema for PySpark Job

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, enums

We have a bunch of disparate pyspark jobs and have a usecase where two jobs can be chained together to form a seperate 3rd job. So if you have one job 'A' and another job 'B' these jobs can be chained together to form another job 'C'. Obviously this can only happen if the output dataframe schema from 'A' is compatible with dataframe schema to 'B'. This is exactly what the dataset api achieves however unfortunately spark doesnt vend dataset for python, understandably because python is dynamically typed. However with the advent of typings we can achieve some sort of compile time safety and I can think of a couple of ways to achieve this, one through composition the other through inheritance.
**Composition**

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from enum import Enum

#Marker Enum
class Schema(Enum):
    pass

T = TypeVar("T", bound = Schema)

class CustomDataSet(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, dataframe: DataFrame) -> None:
        self.dataframe = dataframe
```

Now I can use mypy and use composition like `CustomDataSet[MySchema](dataframe)`. The problem out here is that MySchema is not dataframe object and this can be confusing to someone using this.

**Inheritance**

```
import abc
from enum import Enum

#Marker Enum
class Schema(Enum):
    pass

class MyInterface(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_input_schema() -> Schema:
        raise NotImplementedError
    
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_output_schema() -> Schema:
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Now the two jobs 'A' and 'B' can implement the above interface. This seems a fairly verbose way of doing things and feel not a fan of Inheritance .

My question I have is there a more pythonic way of doing this preferably where I can use composition?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `validate_schema()` method in the [quinn](https://github.com/MrPowers/quinn/) library that throws an exception if a DataFrame schema is different than what's required:

Here's the function in action:

```py
data = [("jose", 1), ("li", 2), ("luisa", 3)]
source_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["name", "age"])
required_schema = StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("city", StringType(), True),
])
quinn.validate_schema(source_df, required_schema) # throws a DataFrameMissingStructFieldError
```

You can validate the schema after you run each job.  The other approaches you've outlined seem a bit overengineered - think it's best to stick to simple functions whenever possible.  Great question.